# Pass values from an HTML E-mail to a PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, html, email

I'm wondering if there is a way to send values from an HTML E-mail to another webpage that will process these values. I'm using PHP at the moment.

I'm composing an HTML template that, depending on the type of mail sent, will trigger a different response depending on values embedded in it at a PHP file in my server. For example, template 1 triggers function1 in PHP, while template 2 triggers function2 in the same PHP file.

The flow is as follows:

The mail takes an external static header with a link to a PHP file, e.g.

```
<div>
   <a href="https://somesite.com/script.php">Click to evaluate Fire or Water</a>
</div>
```

This header is part of the mail, but it's not part of the templates, it is always sent. After this, a template is attached as follows:

Say template 1 has a hidden input type as such:

```
<input type="hidden" name="fire" id="a1" value="Fire" />
```

Template 2 has:

```
<input type="hidden" name="water" id="b1" value="Water" />
```

The email is sent, and whoever receives the email receives a combination of Header and Template1 or Template2 in their body mail. This person clicks the link to evaluate if its Fire or Water, and gets the corresponding result.

Can I read Water or Fire in script.php so that I can echo Water if its template 2, and Fire if it's template 1 when the link is clicked? What could I use to scrape this info from the HTML mail? In the case that I could not edit the hyperlink to the PHP file, does an alternate method than writing the values hardcoded through a GET statement in the URI exist?

I'm using Gmail as a test platform right now, but I realize that they scrub various things such as JavaScript, HTML forms and ID's for protection against cross site injection attacks and vulnerabilities in general. So things like forms don't work for this case. It could also apply to other web mail clients like Hotmail, but for now I'm only testing Gmail.

Comment: Can you just include a URL with some GET parameters ... http://www.example.com/script.php?fire=Fire

Comment: adding to what Chris wrote - you can use a 1x1 pixel image with GET parameters. This won't affect the user experience and you will get your data once the user opened the email instead of clicking on it

Comment: @mele only if the client enables the downloading of external images, which most wont by default

Comment: That's a valid situation I hadn't considered, but it happens that I cannot actually edit the hyperlink to the PHP file. I've updated the question.

Comment: @rtfm the autor question is about gmail and not corporate secured exchange. you in fact can place secured 1x1 image pixel in gmail emails.

Comment: @Eriol can you please elaborate more about the entire flow? The 'input' HTML elements you referrers in the post are part of the email sent to the user? if so you cannot invoke the PHP file without the user clicking the email content and being redirected to external page

Comment: @mele place, but gmail does not load remote images by default.

Comment: @mele It is part of the mail, yes. I realize that hardcoding GET values to the header (e.g. Fire) I can pass Fire, but then I can't implement the dynamic of choosing another case like Water if the template changes.

Comment: @Eriol and when do you invoke the PHP file?

Comment: @rtfm they do load images (from trusted urls) but proxy them. but he will be able to get indication when the image loaded and since he will chain a query string he will be able to get that additional data as well

Comment: depends on your user settings, making this unreliable. Maybe working sometimes but not always is sufficient for the OP

Comment: I would like reliability from it, which is why I'm cracking my head to see if there's any way with the restrictions imposed in the development. If only forms and javascript weren't scrubbed... it would be a security nightmare though. I'll give the image trick a try and see if it works.

Comment: whats the big picture here? i would bet there are better ideas